# Client Denied By Server Apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, internal-server-error

When I try to run an application from localhost, the following message is recorded in `error.log` file

```
[Sat Aug 03 23:05:05 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/xyz/system/
[Sat Aug 03 23:05:05 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/xyz/application/
```

The `.htaccess` file contains

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ xyz/index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ xyz/index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ xyz/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Can someone explain what's happening here and causing this?

Update:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

P.S The application is built using CodeIgniter Framework
Update 2: Permission settings

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 abc abc 4096 Jul 31 22:06 application
-rwxr-xr-x  1 abc abc 2496 Jul 31 22:02 license.txt
drwxr-xr-x  8 abc abc 4096 Jul 31 22:09 system
```

Comment: Does the folder have the right permission ? for instance 777 or 770 or 755 depending on your server setup.

Comment: Can you post your vhost config?

Comment: @JonLin: Have updated the question.

Comment: @Prix: yes. All the necessary permissions are granted.

Comment: @curious_coder If that is not the issue then your folders have the wrong permission which causes apache to deny access to them. Check the apache user and group, the folders chmod, user and group aswell

Comment: @Prix: Have updated with the permission settings.

Comment: Try changing your permissions and then check if it is working. Try :
`chmod -R 777 /var/www/`

Comment: @Shivam: tried... not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve it. The problem was caused due to missing of `index.php`. The file should be present in the folder where application folder and system folder resides.